# Heroku app built with Python and Flask sends JSON response locally, but not on Heroku

Tags: python, json, heroku, socrata

I have a function that is supposed to return a JSON response when there's a GET request on "/query". When I run my application locally this works fine and I can see the data, but when I run my app on Heroku, I get "[]" instead of the data I'm expecting. I have included my code below:

```
import requests
from datetime import date
from requests import Response


@app.route('/query/')                                                           
def request():                                                                  
    # These are the desired columns:                                            
    # ['Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Created Date', 'Agency', 'Agency Name', 'Complaint Type', 'Descriptor']
    columns = "latitude,longitude,created_date,agency,agency_name,complaint_type,descriptor"

    # Get recent service requests (last 6 weeks)                                
    today = date.today()                                                        
    time_delta = today - relativedelta(days=1)                                  
    # Convert datetimes into Floating Timestamps for use with Socrata.          
    today = today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + 'T00:00:00'                            
    time_delta = time_delta.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + 'T00:00:00'                  

    '''                                                                         
    GET request on Socrata's API.                                               
    First part is the data set we're using.                                     
    $limit is set to 500K, because we want 500K records.                        
    $select will select the columns we want, as defined earlier.                
    $where allows us to choose the time frame. In this case it's 6 weeks.       
    '''                                                                         
    r = requests.get(                                                           
        "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/fhrw-4uyv.json?" +              
        "$limit=500000&$select={}&".format(columns) +                           
        "$where=created_date between \'{}\' and \'{}\' and longitude IS NOT NULL".format(time_delta, today)
    )                                                                           

    # Create the response                                                       
    response = Response(response=r, status=200, mimetype='application/json')    
    response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*')                    
    return response
```

Comment: I'm curious if it might be a timezone issue. IIRC, `date.today()` uses the local datetime, and its likely your local TZ and Heroku's are different. Try logging the query string and checking the dates you're generating.

Comment: @chrismetcalf Thanks so much, you were absolutely right. Locally it was taking today's date, but Heroku was one day ahead, so there's actually no data yet! Thanks again!